# Specific heat of vibrating bosons

Tags: calculus, integration, mathematical-physics, change-of-variable

I am trying to understand a solved exercise. It is about calculating the energy of vibrating bosons using the density of states, which is defined as follows:

$$g(\omega) = \frac{9N}{\omega^3_D} \omega$$

Afterwards, the specific heat $c_v$ is calculated ($E = \frac{\partial E}{\partial T}$).

After giving some context, I will go to the point.

$$E = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\hbar \omega g(\omega)}{e^{\beta \hbar \omega} - 1} d\omega = \frac{9N}{\omega^3_D} \int_{0}^{\omega_D} \frac{\hbar \omega^3}{e^{\beta \hbar \omega} - 1} d\omega $$

On this integral, I have to use the following change of variables:

$$x = \beta \hbar \omega$$

$$T_D = \frac{\omega_D \hbar}{K_B}$$

After applying the first one I got:

$$E =\frac{9N}{\omega^3_D \beta^4 \hbar^3} \int_{0}^{\frac{\omega_D}{\beta \hbar}} \frac{ x^3}{e^{x} - 1} dx$$

Where:

$$\beta = \frac{1}{K_BT}$$

Once at this point I applied the second change of variables and derived E with respect to T (Temperature). My issue is that the solved problem skips this calculation and gives directly the $c_v$:

$$ c_v = 9K_BN (\frac{T}{T_D})^3 \int_{0}^{\frac{T_D}{T}} \frac{ x^4 e^x}{(e^{x} - 1)^2} dx$$

But I am not getting this outcome. May you help me out?

Comment: I think this question would be best answered in https://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Gustavo Note that my issue is with the second change of variables and derivative (i.e I am stuck with maths).

Comment: Did you change the upper limit at first substitution?

Comment: Well, I don't see the $T$ variable anywhere in the $E$ formula. So, I don't know how to perform a calculation which does not result zero.

Comment: @Nosrati I did not, good point. Now fixing

Comment: @Gustavo My bad, I edited my question. Please do not hesitate to point out another lacking required definition.

Comment: Use $\dfrac{\partial E}{\partial T}=\dfrac{\partial E}{\partial \beta}\dfrac{\partial\beta}{\partial T}$

Comment: $$\dfrac{\partial E}{\partial T}= \frac{-9N}{\omega^3_D} \int_{0}^{\omega_D} \frac{\hbar^2 \omega^4e^{\beta \hbar \omega}}{(e^{\beta \hbar \omega} - 1)^2} d\omega\times\dfrac{-1}{K_BT^2}$$
now let $\beta \hbar \omega=x$ and simplify.